# Gradle Task does not print on Build Output but builds on Terminal using ./gradlew

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio, gradle

I have a very simple Gradle Task on Android Studio Giraffe, just to print a bunch of Strings. If I print them on the Build output, It never shows but always works when I run it from Terminal. What could be the issue?

using Kotlin DSL, this is the simple tasks I run:

```
tasks.register("taskA") {
    doLast {
        println("I'm taskA")
    }
}

tasks.register("taskB") {
    doLast {
        println("I'm taskB")
    }
}

tasks.register("taskC") {
    doLast {
        println("I'm taskC")
    }
}

tasks.register("taskAll") {
    dependsOn("taskA", "taskB", "taskC")

    doLast {
        println("All Done!")
    }
}
```

This works when I run it on the Terminal using:

```
./gradlew taskA
```

BUT when run on Build Output, it never shows. Please what am I missing?

Comment: Can you attach a screen shot of your android studio build outpu?